# Computing an Interesting limit

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I am trying to figure out the best method to compute the limit:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{xn}{x^3+n}dx.
$$

Some advice/way would be kind

Comment: Hint: write the integrand as $x$ plus a fraction where $n$ appears only in the denominator.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to go about this is to use the inequalities, valid for all $x \in [0,1]$
$$\frac{n}{1+n}x = \frac{xn}{1+n} \leq \frac{xn}{x^3+n} \leq \frac{xn}{n} = x$$
As a consequence
$$
\frac{n}{1+n}\int_0^1 x dx \leq \int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^3+n} dx \leq \int_0^1xdx
$$
Finish up by evaluating the left and right integrals, taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and using the squeeze theorem.